# how about receiving windows messages via Python from Totalcommander

Tags: python-3.x, windows, winapi, total-commander

I'm able to send Windows Messages via Python to Totalcommander with that code

```
import win32gui
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("TTOTAL_CMD", None)          # catch Totalcommander handle
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
nothing = win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, 1075, 4001, 0)     # setting Focus on Totalcommander-left-window
```

But I've no clue how to receive answers of those windows messages which I can sent to Totalcommander too.

When I try that,

```
import win32gui
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("TTOTAL_CMD", None)          # catch Totalcommander handle
buf = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(255)
result_length = win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, 1074, 17, buf)      # getting Path-Info from Window
result = buf[0:result_length*2+2]
tc_path_string = result.decode('utf-16')
```

I'm getting a "'memoryview' object has no attribute 'decode'" at last line

I should get that Info back from Totalcommander- made that working in Autohotkey/AHK from which I now try to change to python.

Jovanni

Comment: Wrong tool. Use [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/) with `backend="uia"`.

Comment: beside controlling Total-Commander, I want getting its list of marked files in Total-commander, therefore I know required WM_Message-Codes from my Autohotkey/AHK programming. So on a first view I couldnt see that pywinauto could solve that to

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) allows you to capture and control virtually any aspect of a UI that implements the required interfaces. Total Commander uses standard Windows controls, which do. Added bonus: You don't need to call `SetForegroundWindow` (which will, eventually, fail).